# Add data to database using entry in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI that allows to the user to manipulate data from mysql database. So the user must add a trip(trip-id, trip-short-name ...) then add stop times for each trip using Entry from tkinter.

```
paths=''
new_trip_id=''


def add_trip():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Trips")
    top.geometry("600x300")
    lbl1 = Label(top, text = 'service_id:', font = {'Helvetica',10})
    lbl1.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.1)
    entry1 = Entry(top)
    entry1.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.1)
    global new_trip_id
    lbl2 = Label(top, text = 'trip_id:', font = {'Helvetica',10})
    lbl2.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.25)
    entry2 = Entry(top)
    entry2.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.25)
    new_trip_id=entry2.get()
    lbl3 = Label(top, text = 'trip_headsign') 
    entry3 = Entry(top)
    entry3.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.4)
    lbl4 = Label(top, text = 'trip_short_name:', font{'Helvetica',10})
    lbl4.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.55)
    entry4 = Entry(top)
    entry4.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.55)
    entry4.bind('<Return>', add_times)
    button1 = Button(top, text="Cancel")
    button1.place(relx=0.5 ,rely=0.7)

def add_times(event):
     mysql.connector("INSERT INTO trips VALUES service_id, trip_id,
     trip_headsign, trip_short_name",
     [enty1.get(), entry2.get(), enty3.get(),
     enty4.get()])
     top = Toplevel()
     top.title("Trips")
     top.geometry("600x300")
```

Ididn't found a solution that allows to the user to add data.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: `Button(..., command=add_times)` ?

Comment: Do you get erro or what ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.